# OpenJDK JVM does not schedule threads on multiple cores

Tags: multithreading, jvm, multicore, java

When I run my multi-threaded Java program on the OpenJDK 6 JVM that is distributed with Ubuntu 12.04, all threads are scheduled on a single core. But when I run the exact same program on the JVM from Oracle's latest 1.7 JDK, it nicely rotates my 20 threads around all 24 available cores. The [OpenJDK documentation](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html) explains that Java threads will be assigned to native threads, but it doesn't seem to be working. Could there be something configured wrong in my OpenJDK installation, or does it not really support multicore hardware?

OpenJDK:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Oracle JDK:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Comment: When I test this on my laptop (which is admittedly running 32 bit) I I see it using all cores (cpu at 395% on my quad core).  This is a brand new (today) install of ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.  `java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)`. I can have a try on my VM a little later but I believe I'll get the same result.  In case it is a bug, what CPU architecture is your server using?

Comment: It's a two-socket board with `AMD Opteron 6168` in both, so 24 cores. The kernel is `Linux 3.2.0-51-generic` (x64). I really have no idea how to investigate something like this, since the JVM by design makes implementation details opaque.

Comment: there is no difference in oracle vs openjdk, but why are you comparing two different versions 1.6 and 1.7, I would compare 1.7 vs 1.7 or 1.6 vs 1.6